# How to delete the space between these two elements with bootstrap grid

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Here is the code of a login form on which I'm working on:

```html
<main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-6">
                <h3 class="display-3">Sign In<h3>
                <form class="justify-content-md-center">
                    <div class="col-md-auto">
                        <input type="text" required placeholder="&#xf2bd; Username" 
                          style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-auto">
                        <input class="margin-25px" type="password" requires
                          placeholder="&#xf023; Password" 
                          style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-fluid row justify-content-md-center">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <img class="icon" src="images/check-box.svg" 
                              alt="check-box">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <p>Forgot your password?</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="login__button btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                        LOGIN
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

I tried to do the layout with bootstrap grid, but can't find how to nest these two object, which are image with the class icon and the paragraph.
[how it looks in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG5nf.png)

Comment: could you please add the CSS related to this snippet? Because I can not reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following lines:

```css
#login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box {
  margin-top: 120px;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 320px;
  border: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
}
#login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box #login-form {
  padding: 20px;
}
#login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box #login-form #register-link {
  margin-top: -85px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<body>
    <div id="login">
        <h3 class="text-center text-white pt-5">Login form</h3>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
                    <div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">
                        <form id="login-form" class="form" action="" method="post">
                            <h3 class="text-center text-info">Login</h3>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username" class="text-info">Username:</label><br>
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
                                <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="remember-me" class="text-info"><span>Remember me</span> <span><input id="remember-me" name="remember-me" type="checkbox"></span></label><br>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="Login">
                            </div>
                            <div id="register-link" class="text-right">
                                <a href="#" class="text-info">Forgot your password ?</a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I already found it in the codepen and I can't remember the author's name to mention here.